# How to return redirect with compact variable in laravel

Tags: laravel, redirect, compact-framework2.0

I have code to do a return redirect as follows

```
public function addWarrent(Request $request)
      {
        $add_warrent = new WarrentModel();
        $add_warrent->id_warrent          = $request->input('id_warrent');
        $add_warrent->workunit_id         = Auth::user()->workunit_id;
        $add_warrent->warr_name           = $request->input('warr_name');
        $add_warrent->warr_position       = $request->input('warr_position');
        $add_warrent->warr_category       = $request->input('warr_category');
        $add_warrent->warr_status         = "Belum Diproses";
        $add_warrent->warr_dt             = Carbon::now();
        $add_warrent->warr_tm             = Carbon::now();
        $add_warrent->save();
    
        Excel::import(new WarrentItemImport, request()->file('warrent_item'));
        
        $warrent_entry_id   = WarrentItemModel::where('warrent_entry_id', null)
                                ->update([
                                  'warrent_entry_id'  => $request->id_warrent,
                                ]);
    
        $add_head_workunit  = WorkunitModel::where('id_workunit', Auth::user()->workunit_id)
                                ->update([
                                  'workunit_head_nip'  => $request->workunit_head_nip,
                                  'workunit_head_name' => $request->workunit_head_name
                                ]);
    
        $id = $request->input('id_warrent');
        return redirect('satker/print_warrent', compact('id'))->with('success','Berhasil Membuat Surat');
      }
```

And then, I got an error message

> Argument 2 passed to
> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse::__construct() must
> be of the type int, array given, called in
> D:\XAMPP\htdocs\Warehouses\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector.php
> on line 233

Why did it happen?

Comment: You can't pass data to redirect like that, use `redirect()->with()`, if you want to include the id in the route, then use the to_route() helper, like : `return to_route('satker.print_warrent', compact('id'))`

Comment: how to call that id inside controller?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/main/ikasmandu?alumni%5Bid_alumni%5D=28. i managed to do a compact return redirect to the controller. then how to call the compacted value in the controller

Comment: You don't call it, it will be provided in the arguments of the method, aka : `method(Request $request, $id)`, assuming your route does contain the `{id}`, like : `satker/print_warrent/{id}`

Comment: Because i use id like this `2022/1.01/ex01`, If I use `satker/print_warrent/{id}`, then I have to set a number of parameters like this `{year}/{no}/{no}/{text}`

Comment: No you can have an id like `2022/1.01/ex01`, better call it something more specific, in your route model binding provider you can do `Route::pattern('complex_id', '[0-9]*[a-z]*\/*\.*')`, and then use it in your route `{complex_id}` and laravel will pass that string to the controller

Answer (score 1):

Try one of following

```
 return redirect('/satker/print_warrent/' . $id)->with('success', 'Berhasil Membuat Surat.');
```

or

```
 return redirect()->route('/satker/print_warrent/')
  ->with(compact('id'))
  ->with('success','Berhasil Membuat Surat');;
```

or

```
 return redirect()->route('/satker/print_warrent/')
   ->with('id', $id)
   ->with('success','Berhasil Membuat Surat');;
```